# Is Rust's borrow checker overly complicating this slices example?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am currently exploring the wonders of Rust by rewriting exercises from [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

I understand both Go and Rust have different features, not everything is fully rewritable and I had my share of fighting the borrow checker. However I got to one fairly simple exercise, yet all solutions I come up with seem very... complex.

**The Go Example**

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  names := [4]string{
    "John",
    "Paul",
    "George",
    "Ringo",
  }
  fmt.Println(names) // [John Paul George Ringo]

  a := names[0:2]
  b := names[1:3]
  fmt.Println(a, b) // [John Paul] [Paul George]

  b[0] = "XXX"
  fmt.Println(a, b) // [John XXX] [XXX George]
  fmt.Println(names) // [John XXX George Ringo]
}
```

In Go we just create 2 slices do a mutation through one and we are done. We do some tradeoff of safety for simplicity thanks to the GC.

**The Rust Example - #1**

```
fn main() {
    let mut names = ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"];
    println!("{:?}", names); // [John Paul George Ringo]

    {
        let a = &names[..2];
        let b = &names[1..3];
        println!("{:?} {:?}", a, b); // [John Paul] [Paul George]
    }

    {
        // need a separate mutable slice identical to 'b'
        let tmp = &mut names[1..3];
        tmp[0] = "XXX";
    }

    {
        // need to assign same variables just to print them out
        let a = &names[..2];
        let b = &names[1..3];
        println!("{:?} {:?}", a, b); // [John XXX] [XXX George]
    }

    println!("{:?}", names); // [John XXX George Ringo]
}
```

This is as close to a one to one rewrite of the previous example as I can get, obviously this is far from optimal due to extra duplicity and overhead involved, so I created a second example.

**The Rust Example - #2**

```
fn slice_writer(arr: &[&str]) {
    let a = &arr[..2];
    let b = &arr[1..3];
    println!("{:?} {:?}", a, b);
}

fn main() {
    let mut names = ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"];
    println!("{:?}", names);

    slice_writer(&names);

    {
        // still need to have the duplicity of '[1..3]'
        let tmp = &mut names[1..3];
        tmp[0] = "XXX";
    }

    slice_writer(&names);

    println!("{:?}", names);
}
```

This feels really cumbersome to write; I need to create a separate function just to remove duplicity of assigning the same slices, a problem I shouldn't have in the first place. Rust creates all these safety measures but it either causes a degradation of performance as we need to create those same variables multiple times, clear them, hold the function in memory, etc. or I need to use some esoteric 'unsafe' procedures and what is the point of using the borrow checker then?

**Summary**

Am I missing something obvious here? What is the simple solution to this problem? Or is this how it is supposed to be done? In that case I can't imagine what it  will be like writing something more massive than a single slice mutating program.

Comment: Hi there! Could you clarify what you are actually asking? If you want to know the best way to translate the Go example and want to get comments on your solutions, you should rather ask on [`codereview.SE`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you want to ask something about the borrow checker, you should (1.) edit your title to reflect that, and (2.) make sure your question is focused: questions like "what's the point of the borrow checker anyway?" are usually way too broad for StackOverflow. Thanks!

Comment: "We do some tradeoff of safety for simplicity thanks to the GC." - how is Go's GC involved in this example?

Comment: *a degradation of performance as we need to create those same variables multiple times* — that's not really how compiled / statically typed languages with optimizing compilers work. Performance can only be decided at the bulk algorithmic level (e.g. `O(N)` vs `O(N^2)`) or via measurement. *clear them* — I don't think there's any such activity here. *hold the function in memory* — it's likely the function is inlined, but the memory difference between the two will be negligible.

Comment: *What is the simple solution to this problem* — I'd probably write it [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5d85f0fbdc9dac5cb82366308e7d8ca8&version=stable). *writing something more massive than a single slice mutating program* — it's very rare, in practice, that you deliberately want to spread out overlapping mutable access, so Rust helps keep you from losing track of all your mutability.

Comment: *is this how it is supposed to be done* — yes, one of Rust's core tenets is that there can only be one thing at a time that is allowed to mutate a value. Amusingly, this is [**even advocated for in a book about programming in Go**](https://books.google.com/books?id=scyH562VXZUC&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=aliasing+xor+mutability&source=bl&ots=MlsexzncZM&sig=jbS4P41bxqKYSHfcNfEDHsxcS0o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy8_bKk-HWAhXKNSYKHb6tAbYQ6AEIRzAG#v=onepage&q=aliasing%20xor%20mutability&f=false) and goes by the same phrase: mutability xor aliasing

Comment: If you're wondering, you *can* [use internal mutability to write something nearly equivalent to the Go version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4b9a483b2960cbce6c16733846b99fdb&version=stable), but at the cost of (1) verbosity and (2) being non-`Sync`. (There is no runtime cost for using `Cell`.)

Comment: Also (3) the debug formatting is not right, but in real life you'd probably wrap this in a zero-overhead type with its own `Debug` impl. Or something like that.

Comment: might also be worth mentioning that the aliasing here is due to the two slices being overlapping (which as noted by others is an anti-pattern also in Go). A similar example with non-overlapping slices is easily written in Rust using [split_at_mut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut)

Answer (score 4):

The Go example is simply not safe. It performs a mutation on aliased memory. If you moved those slices to different threads you could see data races.

Which means the Go compiler cannot perform `noalias` based optimizations. On the other hand the borrow checker in Rust ensure that mutable pointers are not aliased.

> Rust creates all these safety measures but it either causes a degradation of performance as we need to create those same variables multiple times, clear them, hold the function in memory, etc.

Have you actually observed such degradation or compared optimized compiler output?

Comment: *If you moved those slices to different threads* — FWIW, I'd expect a response around the lines of "but I'm not using multiple threads so this doesn't matter", so you might want to prepare a rebuttal if you feel like it.

Comment: Pro hint: a trivial `memcpy` implementation would have serious issues in some cases of aliased memory ranges.